# Vertically center a checkbox within a div

Tags: html, css, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I have a `checkbox` within a `div` that is appearing higher than the text I want it to be aligned with.

Here's how it appears in Firefox:

[image]

As you can see, the `checkbox` is just a few pixels higher than the text. I have tried applying various padding / margins, including negative values, but to no avail.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="read-confirm-box">
  I Have read the above 
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#read-confirm-box
{
    color: #FFF;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 11px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}

#checkbox 
{
    /* Empty */
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcM56/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="read-confirm-box">
  I Have read the above 
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#read-confirm-box
{
    color: #FFF;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 11px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}

#checkbox 
{
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap both text and `input` into a div, It's a good practice.

To align both the `divs` containing text and control accordingly, use [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) properties

Try:

**HTML**

```
<div id="read-confirm-box">
    <div class="inline">I Have read the above </div>
    <div class="inline"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /></div>
</div>
```

---

```
 <label for="checkbox">I Have read the above </label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

---

```
<span>I Have read the above </span>
<span><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.inline{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hkz3h/)

[**<kbd>Updated</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/hkz3h/2/)

Comment: Logically the first div should be a `<label>. :)

Comment: Yeah `<label for=''>` :)

Comment: Better to use `<span>` element as an inline wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following css.

```
#checkbox {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Only works with multiple elements that have `display:inline-block`

Comment: @Paulie_D You could verify that: Another example including an image http://jsbin.com/hedag/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is likely higher for lack of a reset.css (browsers apply their own defaults).

For usability, you should use the `label` element, rather than wrapping the input and text in extra `divs`.

Give the `input` and `label` the same margin and voila!

**HTML**

```
<div id="read-confirm-box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox">I Have read the above </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#read-confirm-box {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 11px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}

input {
   margin: 3px;
}

label {
    float:left;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djungle/x6EUp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy fix.
CSS:

```
#checkbox {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when that's the only css you apply on the checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

Or as an alternative, forking that fiddle: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcM56/1/)**

```
#checkbox 
{
    vertical-align:-2px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't. But it depends on the size of the font: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/vcM56/3/

Comment: >Hashem...As does the accepted answer... >Dhaval yes, vertical-align can take a value of measurement